# Re draw the nv d3 chart while clicking on the x-axis focus/scroll/zoom in nv d3 js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am new to NV D3 js. I am preparing lineplusbar with focus chart. I am getting the plot correctly. my question is I want to draw the separate chart/add new line to existing chart while moving the focus bar on X-Axis.

Is it possible to re draw the new chart while click on the focus bar of previous chart.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. It sounds as if you want to link two different charts, which isn't possible in NVD3 directly. You would need to write code to do that yourself.

Comment: Ty for reply.. Is it possible to get focused area x and y values. if yes please let me know how do get selected area x and y values.